# Swift - SearchController's navigation item is not at top assert

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchcontroller

I am facing following issue while adding searchcontroller into custom navigation bar.

2020-05-20 19:53:18.669036+0530 DiffableTableView[27679:1184112] [Assert] Surprise! Activating a search controller whose navigation item is not at the top of the stack. This case needs examination in UIKit. items = (null),
search hosting item =  title='Guest' hidesBackButton rightBarButtonItems=0x600000bfccd0 searchController=0x7fade707e800 hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling
2020-05-20 19:53:18.669211+0530 DiffableTableView[27679:1184112] [Assert] Unexpected code path for search bar hosted by navigation bar. This is a UIKit problem.

```
let customNavigationItem: UINavigationItem = {
    let navigationItem = UINavigationItem()
    navigationItem.title = "Invite Guest"
    navigationItem.setRightBarButton(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .close, target: self, action: #selector(closeButtonPressed)), animated: true)
    navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    return navigationItem
  }()

lazy var navigationBar: UINavigationBar = {
    let navigationBar = UINavigationBar()
    navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    navigationBar.items = [customNavigationItem]
    navigationBar.sizeToFit()
    navigationBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return navigationBar
  }()

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    customNavigationItem.searchController = searchController
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `navigationController` of your `viewController's` property. If it's nil, then you'll have such message. At least it was the reason of problem in my case.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail? Sample code? Where should we check?